# Tests with @DataJpaTest are not using embedded in-memory database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

As per the [DataJpaTest documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) tests annotated with `@DataJpaTest` will by default use embedded in-memory database(h2)

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and
> roll back at the end of each test. They also use an embedded in-memory
> database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured
> DataSource). The @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation can be used to
> override these settings.

But in my case it is not happening, Test class annotated with `@DataJpaTest` is loading the postgres dialect instead of using h2 dialect.

Below is the property file from main/resources

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=test
    username: test
    password: test
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Whats happening**

I found that spring is not picking dialect from `application.yml` file from main/resources instead of honouring `@DataJpaTest` and using h2 dialect.

**Solution**

While trying different variations with jpa properties, I found that this issue is happening only when `database-platform` property is present in the application properties file. If this property is removed then its loading the h2 dialect for test cases and postgres dialect of main application.

**Why?**

This seems to be a bug in the spring codebase, since it is nowhere documented that one needs to remove `database-platform` property for `@DataJpaTest` to use in-memory database.

Also there is one more confusion around `database-platform` property, as per [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.jpa.properties)

> spring.jpa.database-platform
>
> Name of the target database to operate on, auto-detected by default.
> Can be alternatively set using the "Database" enum.

Seems like one more bug in the documentation, as the `spring.jpa.database-platform` only accepts dialect class as a value and no other enum value will work.